# Image script wont work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome

I've just redesigned my website, and seemingly all is well. However someone has pointed out that the image galleries are not viewable correctly in chrome. It's driving me mad, and I can't work it out. Can anyone spot an obvious mistake? Thanks a lot.

The URL is: http://www.create-imaginations.com/

Comment: How much are you going to pay me to fix your web site?

Comment: They definitely look fake and super-imposed.  Is that the mistake?

Comment: Very nice looking site. But you are obviously using DreamWeaver behaviors. Is your software outdated? The MM_ prefixes on the javascript functions make me think you may be using an old version.

Comment: No need to be rude here, lest I remind ye the FAQ says "Be nice".  @Stormyuk, it would be more helpful if you posted the *onclick* handler code for your image gallery.

Comment: Disregard my comment. I just checked DreamWeaver CS5 and it uses those same behaviors. I haven't used DreamWeaver since the Macromedia days, so that's why it looked old to me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug in chrome that it will not fire a mouse over event on an image. There are a few ways of solving it:

- Surrounding each of your images in a `div` tag and adding the events to the `div` tag and leaving the events on the image as well.
- Moving the events to the `a` tag

These should mean that it will work, however if all else fails, you could create a `div` in place of the image tag and use styles to set the `div`'s background image using

```
<div style="background-image:'<IMAGE URL HERE>';" <EVENT TRIGGERS> ></div>
```

However this will reduce compatibility with browsers that don't support CSS.

**Browser Support for CSS:**

Internet Explorer 5 and above.
Firefox 1 and above.
Safari 1 and above.
And all newer browsers like chrome
(http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css_browser_sup.htm)

Considering that in 2008, on  [W3Cchools](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) only 0.3% of users used IE 5. So compatibility, is not likely to be an issue.

Comment: Which browsers don't support CSS, and would the site even be remotely usable on one of them anyway?

Comment: See edit on Browser Compatibility. And in my belief, it is not going to be an issue.